# If NID doesn't exist, save node?

Tags: entities

I'm using menu_get_object() to get the NID for a computed field. The problem is that on a node save, NID doesn't exist yet so the computed field produces an error. If I resave the node, everything works since now the NID exists for the computed field to refer to. How can I go about adding an IF statement that if NID doesn't exist, save the node?

```
$node = menu_get_object();
$assigned_uid = $node->field_agent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
$assigned_user = user_load($assigned_uid);
$percentage_split = $assigned_user->field_percentage_split[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

$other_ins = (isset(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_other_ins_')[0]) ? field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_other_ins_')[0]['value'] : 0);
$vb = (isset(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_vb')[0]) ? field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_vb')[0]['value'] : 0);
$finder_s_fee = (isset(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_finder_s_fee')[0]) ? field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_finder_s_fee')[0]['value'] : 0);
$broker_fee = (isset(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_broker_fee')[0]) ? field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_broker_fee')[0]['value'] : 0);
$dlc_franchise_fee_hst = (isset(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_franchise_fee_hst')[0]) ? field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_franchise_fee_hst')[0]['value'] : 0);

$value = (($other_ins + $vb + $finder_s_fee + $broker_fee) - $dlc_franchise_fee_hst ) * ($percentage_split/100);
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the top of your code:

```
global $node;
if (empty($node->nid)) {
  node_save($node);
}
```

Worked for me in D5 and D6.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get an error but also nothing is computed, even on resave.

Comment: Try commenting out _$node = menu_get_object();_.

Comment: No error, but again without $node = menu_get_object();, assigned_uid doesn't know what $node is.

Comment: The replace _global $node;_ with _$node = menu_get_object;_ and see what happens. With the two in play, the question is which $node are you looking at!

Comment: Really appreciate the help. Now I get this error `Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7633...` I think that the $node->nid part is the problem. Before the menu_get_object(); solution, we had quite a bit of trouble determining the NID.

Comment: I think that the menu_get_object is the issue since on content creation, the path isn't node/%node. I've replaced it with this, which makes more sense but still having to save it twice `$mynid = $entity->nid;
$node=node_load($mynid);`

Comment: How many times do you think you have to load the node! Nothing will compute on your first $node if you overwrite it before you do the calculations. Load ONCE! If $node is already available, just declare it with global $node otherwise use menu get object. NOT BOTH. Then check your $node to see if $node->nid is set. If not use node_save(). Then do your calculations without reloading your node.

Comment: I am not using both, just trying one or the other. It seems as though node_save() will not work in a computed field. The more I work on this, the more it seems that a custom module may be the best way. I've looked into using rules to set the field value after node save but doing the php there is hurting my brain.

Comment: Just an update on this. I used Rules instead of computed fields to do this. It saved me from having to do the first step of finding the NID and having to resave. I just set it to set the field value based on the calculations after node save and on update.